# How does the med, Spironolactone, help with PCOS?

Tags: medications, dosage, pcos, hormonal-imbalance, cystic-acne

I've been taking Spironolactone for my acne for many years (I'm a woman in my late 20's now). I have been taking it for this intended purpose. The other day,  a doctor was looking over my meds and for what purpose I take them for, and said, "I assume you're taking Spironolactone for your PCOS, yeah?" I told him it was for my adult acne, but I do in fact have PCOS. He was surprised I wasn't taking it for PCOS. I've never heard of Spironolactone being used for PCOS... and now I'm curious:

**How does the med, Spironolactone, help with PCOS?**

**Would the Spironolactone I'm taking for acne also be helping my PCOS, and I just never knew about it?** *Or do you need a much higher dosage when using it for PCOS instead of acne?*

Comment: https://www.sepalika.com/pcos/spironolactone-for-pcos/